# Bad Request on ASP.NET SQL Server query on id more than 32768

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-6

I've a website which is using ASP.NET / IIS / SQL Server.

Things going smooth before, but when the data in SQL Server exceeds id of 32768, my website throws a **Bad Request** error. All of the ids after 32768 are showing the exact same error, while 32767 and below seems fine.

Does anyone have any idea regarding this problem?

Comment: Does your SQL Server table that you're working with happen to have a `SMALLINT` column?? Those are limited to +/- 32'768 .....

Comment: @marc_s the records is in INT and there are already values exceeding 32768. The only problem is the website will displayed Bad Request when querying on that id or more.